# Где реализовать логику определения в запросе к БД или в приложении

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть таблица в БД MS SQL, которая обновляется раз в N минут, таблица хранит статично 32 записи. В таблице хранится время определенных чекпоинтов, всего чекпоинтов 5, значение равно `NULL` пока чекпоинт не наступит. Мне необходимо выводить пользователю определенный цвет в интерфейс приложения на `WinFoms` в зависимости какие чекпоинты уже пройдены. При помощи `SqlDependency` я понимаю, когда таблица получила новые данные. Я начинающий C# программист и не знаю какой подход будет более правильный. Я рассматриваю вариант сделать в запросе к таблице столбец где при помощи `case when` буду присваивать своего рода `id_status` в зависимости от того, какие временные поля имеют `NULL`, в ПО при помощи  того же `switch` после вычитки запроса менять цвет объекта согласно полученной цифры. Собственно вопрос, что лучше:

1. Передать всю информацию результата запроса в ПО и в ПО уже прописывать логику определения какой нужно вывести цвет
2. Или в ПО передавать уже результат и согласно этого результата присваивать цвет?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд логично было бы чтобы ХП из БД возвращала вам статус, а уже на стороне С#, например при помощи таймера вы бы отслеживали изменение этого статуса и красили цвет.

Comment: Так долго ждал совета, что так и сделал. Запрос возвращает мне `id` статуса и согласно его я меняю цвет.